# C# hidding interface members

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following code:

```
interface IA
{
   string text {get;}
}
interface IB: IA
{
   int number {get;}
}
class MyType: IB
{
   {...}
}
```

I realy don't want to implement property "text" from IA in MyType.. Is there any possible trick? For example, IB hides property..

Thanks

Comment: Why do you extend `IB` with `IA` if you don't want it to have valid interface?

Comment: Interface is a contract and there is no way around it.

Comment: @zerkms: Because i need that MyType also is an IA type...

Comment: @Nabo: `MyType is IA` means that it **does have** `text` property

Comment: Bah! I KNOW THAT!!!! My question is just if it is any trick. I it isn't, just say that, and i will mark it as right answer...

Comment: All the answers you need have been provided. Basically, you cannot and should not implement a type without honouring the contract. There is no need to resort to shouting.

Comment: @Nabo The answer is no. The closest thing is explicit implementation but it is still implementation and because of the interface inheritance that you have going on, wouldn't help your case.

Comment: This isn't an outrageous question. It may not be his choice whether `IB` inherits `IA`. `IB` could be a third party product, or even part of the BCL. He wants some, perhaps even most, of the behaviors of the interface, just not all.  `IList` is just one example from the BCL of an interface that is not always fully implemented. Maybe it's a problem with the interface, but it is what it is.

Comment: @Anthony, it's not outrageous in a general sense, but it is outrageous from a technical sense. If `IB` implements `IA`, and `MyType` implements `IB`, it's a foregone conclusion that `MyType` implements `IA`. There is absolutely nothing you can do about it, short of implementing user791928's answer.

Answer (score 11):

Yeah, you can make it pseudo-private by implementing it explicitly like this:

```
class MyType: IB
{
    string IA.text { get { throw new NotSupportedException(); } }
}
```

But like, really? Violating your own contract is, like, well, ... a Violation, man!

Have fun using it I guess?

Comment: if you add ", man" to the end of your last statement, you get a +1 from me.

Comment: This is implementing the property.. Simply the implementation is throwing an exception. I don't want to write anything related to IA in MyType

Comment: This is the correct answer, but the idea that **you should never do this** hasn't been stressed quite enough.

Comment: *Never* is a bit strong. With extreme rarity, perhaps.

Comment: Again correct answer but @Kirk Woll never is a very strong word. Whilst I agree Explicit interface member implementation shouldn't be used in the OP's case (Throwing NotImplementedException would be better) there are times when it is extremely useful such as a fluent interface where several interfaces are implemented on the same object but you do not want to expose all the methods at the same time.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: You know what, let Nabo do this, and let's make sure that we never do this ourselves. Is this rare enough? =)

Comment: You people misunderstand. I have **no** problem with explicit interface implementations.  I have an **extreme** problem with throwing a `NotImplementedException` in order to "not implement" a method in an interface that **I** wrote.  It is categorically a bad design.

Comment: @user, I would suggest that you update the answer to follow an established pattern for this frowned upon practice, and that is use a `NotSupportedException` rather than `NotImplementedException`. I would also, if I were in the unfortunate position of making this decision, document the heck out of it.

Comment: @Anthony: Changed it for you.